# Finding characteristic polynomial of n x n matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, characteristic-functions

I'm having some problems with this question. Usually, I would just subtract I*x where x is the eigenvalue, and take the determinant of the matrix. Then I would solve for x using the quadratic formula or factoring. But I definitely can't do that here. How can I approach this problem? I'm very lost

[image: question]

Comment: I would suggest trying the $n=2$ and $n=3$ cases first.

Comment: Try it for some small examples and see what the pattern is. Alternatively, look up Leslie matrices (this is a well studied type of matrix, and yours is related closely)

Comment: To see how it looks, you can see here: http://www.engr.mun.ca/~millan/Eng6825/canonicals.pdf
"1.2 Observable Canonical Form" and compare the matrix to the denominator of the system function.

Comment: Your matrix is in [Companion form](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Denote the given $n \times n$ matrix by $C[a_0, \ldots, a_{n - 1}]$. As you've mentioned the characteristic polynomial is (up to a sign convention) $$c[a_0, \ldots, a_{n - 1}](t) := \det(t I_n - C[a_0, \ldots, a_{n - 1}]) .$$
Computing the determinant using the cofactor expansion along the top row---which has only two nonzero entries, we find that $(1, 1)$ minor is the $(n - 1) \times (n - 1)$ matrix $t I_{n - 1} - C[a_1, \ldots, a_{n - 1}]$, and so
\begin{align*}
c[a_0, \ldots, a_{n - 1}](t)
&= t \det (t I_{n - 1} - C[a_1, \ldots, a_{n - 1}]) + (-1)^n a_0 \det I_{n - 1} \\
&= t c[a_1, \ldots a_n] + (-1)^n a_0 .
\end{align*}

> We have now given an expression for $c[a_0, \ldots, a_{n - 1}](t)$ in terms of $c[a_1, \ldots a_n]$ and $a_0$, which suggests an inductive approach: Compute $c[a_0, \ldots, a_{n - 1}]$ for $n = 1, 2, 3$, after which the pattern should be apparent, and use the above identity to prove that the pattern holds for all $n$. **Remark**: Such matrices have the form of [companion matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix).